# how to display different images if combination radio buttons checked?

Tags: javascript

There are 4 groups of radio buttons and displayed image of interior design. Would like to do presentation showing kitchen design with different finishes. How the javascript code should look like to display suitable image when one button from each group of finishes(wall color,cabinet color, countertop color and flooring) checked?
[image: screenshot]

```
    <div id="nav">
     <legend>Flooring</legend>
      <input type="radio" id="1" name="floor"onClick="changeSrc()"> Boardwalk<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="2" name="floor"onClick="changeSrc()"> Cognac<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="3" name="floor"onClick="changeSrc()"> Java Fossilized<br/>
     <input type="radio" id="4" name="floor"onClick="changeSrc()"> Mocha<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="5" name="floor"onClick="changeSrc()"> Treehouse<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="6" name="floor"onClick="changeSrc()"> Natural<br/><br/>


      <legend>Cabinet</legend>
      <input type="radio" id="7" name="Cabinet"onClick="changeSrc()"> Gray<br/> 
      <input type="radio" id="8" name="Cabinet"onClick="changeSrc()"> Bordeaux<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="9" name="Cabinet"onClick="changeSrc()"> Linen White<br/> 
      <input type="radio" id="10" name="Cabinet"onClick="changeSrc()"> Natural Wood<br/><br/>

      <legend>Wall Color</legend>
      <input type="radio" id="11" name="wall color"> Berkshire Beige<br/> 
      <input type="radio" id="12" name="wall color"> Coastal Fog<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="13" name="wall color"> Linen White<br/> 
      <input type="radio" id="14" name="wall color"> Metropolitan<br/><br/> 

     <legend>Countertop</legend>
      <input type="radio" id="15" name="Countertop"onClick="changeSrc()"> Altair<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="16" name="Countertop"onClick="changeSrc()"> Desert Silver<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="17" name="Countertop"onClick="changeSrc()"> Ironbark<br/>
     <input type="radio" id="18" name="Countertop"onClick="changeSrc()"> Kimbler Mist<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="19" name="Countertop"onClick="changeSrc()"> Mountain Mist<br/>
      <input type="radio" id="20" name="Countertop"onClick="changeSrc()"> Royal Reef<br/><br/>
</div>

    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <img id="myImage" width=1320px src="img/kitchenBoardwalk.jpg"/>
```

```js
function changeSrc() {
    if (document.getElementById("1").checked & document.getElementById("7").checked & document.getElementById("11").checked & document.getElementById("15").checked) {
    document.getElementById("MyImage").src = "img/kitchenBoardwalk.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you wanted Java and not Javascript? HTML usually goes together with Javascript, not Java. Also, where is your code? Where in your code did you have trouble?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     function changeSrc() {
        if (document.getElementById("1").checked & document.getElementById("7").checked & document.getElementById("11").checked & document.getElementById("15").checked) {
    document.getElementById("MyImage").src = "img/kitchenBoardwalk.jpg";
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such context, is always a good idea to preload the image even before you dynamically assign it to a **src** attribute. Without such, the browser can't update the DOM in real time in such context.

Do this:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'img/kitchenBoardwalk.jpg';
```

This should be done before **changeSrc()** declaration.

In your function, change this line:

> document.getElementById("MyImage").src = "img/kitchenBoardwalk.jpg"

To:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = image.src;
```

Note that you can add other properties such **height, width, alt** etc to the **image** object/instance.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: function changeSrc() {
      var image = new Image();
   image.src = 'img/kitchenBoardwalk.jpg';{
   if (document.getElementById("1").checked & document.getElementById("7").checked & document.getElementById("11").checked & document.getElementById("15").checked) {
        document.getElementById("MyImage").src = image.src;
   }

Comment: Wil be like this ?

Comment: var image = new Image(); image.src = 'img/kitchenBoardwalk.jpg'; function changeSrc() {  if (document.getElementById("1").checked & document.getElementById("7").checked & document.getElementById("11").checked & document.getElementById("15").checked) { document.getElementById("MyImage").src = image.src; }} <-- this rather.

Comment: In HTML before "changeSrc()" should be onclick or checked?

Comment: use `onclick='changeSrc()'` in your HTML AND NOT `onClick` as in capital 'C'

Comment: var image = new Image();
image.src = 'img/kitchenCognac.jpg';
    function changeSrc() {
     if (document.getElementById("2").checked & document.getElementById("7").checked & document.getElementById("11").checked & document.getElementById("15").checked) {
          document.getElementById("MyImage").src = image.src;
     }

Comment: In your HTML code -->       `<input type="radio" id="1" name="floor"onClick="changeSrc()"> Boardwalk<br/>` should be       `<input type="radio" id="1" name="floor"onclick="changeSrc()"> Boardwalk<br/>` You used capital 'C' or camel case notation as in `onClick` which is not acceptable, conversely, it should be `onclick` thus all in 'lower-case'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I understood and changed to 'lower-case' and still doesn't work.

Comment: Please check the console and let's see any error it prints. Also check to see if the image you preloaded is within the browser even before you trigger the click event.

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: ooh okay.. change `MyImage` to `myImage` to match the ID in the HTML. So now it should be `document.getElementById("myImage").src = image.src;`. JS is case sensitive. It should work now.

Comment: :) Yes first image displayed. I will try with others. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: You're very welcome, please upvote/mark my answer then as being useful. Thanks. :)

Comment: How Can I do it?

Comment: Thanks dear, I can see you've marked it as correct.

Comment: If I want use other image, just need to copy entire this script and change id and image name?

Comment: Yeah.. that's when you've literally defined several `<img>` in your HTML. But if you want to just dynamically show different images in the one `<img> src` which has **ID** of **myImage**, then you'll have to preload them as this (assuming I have image1.jpg & image2.jpg). var image = new Image(); var imageOne = image.src = 'img/image1.jpg'; var imageTwo = image.src = 'img/image2.jpg' and so on and so forth. if they are plenty say from a database, then you can preload them and keep their references in an array.This works for me in my projects when I have to preload 3 to about 7 images.

Comment: var image = new Image();
var imageOne = image.src = 'img/kitchenCognac.jpg';
var imageTwo = image.src = 'img/kitchenNatural.jpg';
function changeSrc() {
if (document.getElementById("2").checked & document.getElementById("7").checked & document.getElementById("11").checked & document.getElementById("15").checked) 
{document.getElementById("myImage").src = imageOne.src;}}
{if (document.getElementById("6").checked & document.getElementById("7").checked & document.getElementById("11").checked & document.getElementById("15").checked) 
{document.getElementById("myImage").src = imageTwo.src;}}

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: You're very welcome dear. I was asleep.. I'm glad is okay.